# Add a new column in table using .orm.yml configuration

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, yaml, symfony-2.3

I have a question for you. It's possible to add a new column for a table using .orm.yml configuration?

For example I have :

```
Shop\DesktopBundle\Entity\Order:
type: entity
repositoryClass: Shop\DesktopBundle\Repository\OrderRepository
table: order
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    order_adresse:
        type: string
        length: 255
    order_date:
        type: datetime
    is_active:
        type: boolean
        nullable: true
    created_at:
        type: datetime
oneToMany:
    Cart:
         targetEntity: Cart
         mappedBy: carts
manyToOne:
        category:
            targetEntity: Customer
            inversedBy: orders
            joinColumn:
                name: customer_id
                referencedColumnName: id
manyToMany:
    categories:
        targetEntity: Product
        joinTable:
            name: order_details
            joinColumns:
                order_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                product_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ setCreatedAtValue ]
```

So I tried to add the column "quantity" in relation many to many > order_details table

Comment: Did you regenerate your entity `doctrine:generate:entity` ?

Comment: doctrine:schema:update or better with doctrine migrations

Comment: but this is table order not order details. you want to add quantity to order_details use your yml of order_details entity. and in your fields add quantity

Comment: Look at the relation manyToMany I have there the table order_details

Comment: You cannot add properties to a ManyToMany relation.  You will need to make an entity called OrderDetail and define OneToMany relations between Order and Product.  Same sort of thing you did with Order linking Customer and Cart.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to add `quantity` to the relation not to the table. Try this:

```
manyToMany:
    categories:
        targetEntity: Product
        joinTable:
            name: order_details
            joinColumns:
                order_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                product_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
fields: # if you already have 'fields' append to it
    quantity:
        type: int
```

A good example of setting your entity using yml is here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html#example

Comment: Not works...the column is not added to table order_details....I generate entity with doctrine:generate:entity and I do doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: @Gigel, can you give the complete yml file?

Comment: You cannot add attributes to a ManyToMany relation.  Have to add a new entity and use OneToMany relations.